# Is there a way to retreive the collection items from Textbox - AutoCompleteCustomSource in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

On executing the below code, I am successfully able to insert an array values into a Textbox AutoCompleteCustomSource.

But I need to be able to read all data back from the AutoCompleteCustomSource too, and put it into an array.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource

    Dim Arr1 As String() = {"Hello", "How", "Are", "You"}

    'Below line of code puts all the array values into TxtBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(Arr1)


    '-------------Need Help on Below-------
    'How to read all data from TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource and bring it into an array
    Dim MyArr1
    MyArr1 = TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource??????????????????????????????????????

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw a bit of LINQ at it:

```vb
Dim items = TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Cast(Of String)().ToArray()
```

The `AutoCompleteCustomSource` is type `AutoCompleteStringCollection`, which implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable(Of T)`, although every item is guaranteed to be a `String`. That means that you can call the `Cast(Of String)` extension method to get an `IEnumerable(Of String)` and then call `ToArray` on that to get a `String` array.

Other options include this:

```vb
Dim source = TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource
Dim items(source.Count - 1) As String

source.CopyTo(items, 0)
```

or you can go really old-school with this:

```vb
Dim source = TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource
Dim upperBound = source.Count - 1
Dim items(upperBound) As String

For i = 0 To upperBound
    items(i) = source(i)
Next
```